# sudo: PAM authentication error: Module is Unknown

Tags: ubuntu, pam

PAM Authentication Error

Hello! I made a typo in the /etc/pam.d/common-password file, and now when I try to use sudo for anything I get the following error:

sudo: PAM authentication error: Module is unknown

Root user login is disabled on my system, is there a way to still fix this? I am typing in my password correctly. I was able to use sudo for a while to move/create files and directories, but the problem started when I needed to use nano. Now, I cannot use sudo at all. There are other administrators on the machine I can login to, but I'm nervous that if I log out of my account I won't be able to access it again. Thanks for the help in advance!

So far I have tried placed vi /etc/pam.d/sudo. When I entered my password, it said my password was wrong even though I typed it in correctly.

Comment: Try booting into single user mode, or boot changing init at boot to /bin/sh, or boot from a iso/usb, mount the partition & fix it that way.